# understanding higher order function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

```
f::Char->String->String
f ch str
    |('a'<=ch&&ch<='z')=ch:str
    |otherwise=str
```

The output seems really counter-intuitive to me:

```
*Main> foldr f "END" "xYz1Ab"
"xzbEND"
*Main> foldr f "xYz1Ab" "END" 
"xYz1Ab"
```

My train of thoughts is that "End" is ch and "xYz1Ab" is str, so `foldr f "END" "xYz1Ab"` is  supposed to be "ENDxzb" and `foldr f "xYz1Ab" "END"` is suppsoed to be "END". Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

None of the characters in `"END"` match the guard `('a'<=ch&&ch<='z')`, so they're not appended.

The second argument to `foldr` is the initial state, that's always passed in as `str`, never as `ch`.

Comment: but the declaration is f ch str and the input is  f "END" "xYz1Ab",shouldn't ch be correspond to "END" and str be "xYz1Ab"?

Comment: But you didn't write `f "END" "xYz1Ab"`, you wrote `foldr f "END" "xYz1Ab"`. In the first case, the two strings are arguments to the `f` function (leaving aside the fact that `f`'s first argument should be a `Char`, not a `String`). In the second case, `f`, `"END"` and `"xYz1Ab"` are all arguments to the `foldr` function. If you'd written `foldr (f "END" "xYz1Ab")`, then the strings would be `f`'s arguments, but of course that's another type error.